# При отправки post запроса выходит ошибка

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Хочу на одной странице вывести список задач и форму, с помощью которой можно добавить новую задачу. Через форму необходимо присвоить только name, id и date присваиваются автоматически. Но при загрузки формы выходит ошибка:

> **org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException:** Error during
> execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
> (template: "index" - line 11, col 31)
>
> **Caused by**: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor
> plain target object for bean name 'task' available as request
> attribute

Код HTML с формой и списком задач

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Добавить дело</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/task}"
      th:object="${task}" method="post">
  <p>Дело: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Добавить" /></p>
</form>
<h1>Список дел</h1>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Дело</th>
    <th>Время добавления</th>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each ="task : ${tasks}">
    <td th:utext="${task.name}">...</td>
    <td th:utext="${task.date}">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Get и post метод для отправки запросов.

```
public class TaskController {
@Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @PostMapping("/task")
    public String post(@ModelAttribute Task task, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("task", dao.post(task));
        return "result";
    }

    @GetMapping("/task")
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("task", new Task());
        model.addAttribute("tasks", dao.index());
        return "task";
    }

    @GetMapping("/task/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable int id) {
        return dao.get(id);
    }
}
```

```
public class TaskDaoImpl implements Dao 
 @Autowired
    TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Task> index() {
        Iterable<Task> taskIterable = taskRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Task task : taskIterable) {
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity get(int id) {
        Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(id);
        return optionalTask.map(task -> new ResponseEntity(task, HttpStatus.OK)).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null));
    }

    @Override
    public int post(Task task) {
        Task newTask = taskRepository.save(task);
        return newTask.getId();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String date = (new Date()).toString();


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return  date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Предполагаю что ошибка кроется в методах. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: то, что начал правильно код форматировать - молодец. то, что ответ мой удалил - не молодец, можно было бы в рамках того ответа дописать вопросы в комментариях если бы они возникли и там довести ответ до решения

Comment: код HTML полностью приведен? что-то у меня не матчится особо 11 строка и 31 символ

Comment: Теперь код HTML полностью приведен

Comment: единственное, что меня смущает - это наличие двух переменных task на странице. непосредственно в форме и при итерации. поменяйте `task` в при  итерации на `item`...

Comment: `<tr th:each ="item : ${tasks}"><td th:utext="${item.name}">...</td><td th:utext="${item.date}">...</td></tr>`

Comment: Погодите...а Task у вас прям один-в-один так и лежит в коде?..то что в вопросе это точная копия?

Comment: это весь код класса Task?.. если да - то в нем проблема